# Flutter app crashes when resuming to type

Tags: android, flutter

I have a very simple test app that only requires users to type some text in a text box.

However when the user types few words, closes the keyboard and then taps on the text box to resume typing, the app would basically freezes from working. None of the buttons would work and the user will have force close to open the app again.

The only time that it doesn't freeze is to tap between the words that the user has already typed. If the user try to type from where they stopped then the app freezes.

It's happening on all of these physical devices.
    Samsung Galaxy A20
    Samsung Galaxy A7
    Samsung Galaxy M30S

Unfortunately no logs as I don't have access to these devices.

My main.dart

```
import 'package:anasislam/view/test_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      //Route
      initialRoute: 'testScreen',
      routes: {
        'testScreen': (context) => TestScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

My test_screen.dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return
              SafeArea(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Type here',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
          }),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting the same error, change your flutter channel to Beta and this problem shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. First, make a new flutter project using flutter create in an empty folder and test to see if it repeats the same problem. If you are running flutter version 1.20.1 and up, try running  `flutter --version` then `flutter clean` then `flutter downgrade 1.19.0-4.1.pre` then `flutter clean`. if you are not already, i would advise going to the beta channel using `flutter channel beta`. make sure to delete the app of the devices and clear the cache or restart them before installing a new flutter app after downgrade. I think the powersaving feature intoduced in the latest builds has an issue resuming some background tasks such as the onscreen keyboard. please let me know if this helpped as i am trying to resolve this too. Just wondering if the issue started the first time you suspended a flutter app with the keyboard still active and now it happens every time you susspend the app regardless of the keyboard as that is how it presented with me. it also effected all flutter apps on that test device and caused a memory issue (GLES ctx: 0x7e0aa0c008, error code:0x505) which i havent been able to find any info on.

Comment: Hi Jack, I can confirm changing the flutter channel will resolve the problem. I didn't downgrade the flutter version. Back then and now I'm still using Flutter 1.17.0-3.3.pre. I added a comment here too but it was deleted by few members! 


FYI, I had another problem after release and that was the app would crash before opening. Error was

`Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
Couldn't load flutter from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/uk.user.anasislam-1.apk"] ...`
To resolve this I released the app using APK instead of bundle.

Comment: Aw, thanks! that was really helpful for me too. Its strange that the last major flutter update  didnt address this bug and the one with the "recent view" spawning a memory leak on android 7. thanks for replying too